# lodash deep nested array filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have a complex nested array of objects like this for which I have to return a new Array(filter) based on `attributeScore > 90`. How will I accomplish this using the javascript .filter or the lodash _.find() or _.some function ?

```
trucks:[
     {wheels:[
             {name:"xyz",
              mechanics: [
                     {engine:'50cc',
                     attributeScore:100},
                     {....} ,{...}
                    ]
              },
              {name:"gcd",
              mechanics: [
                     {engine:'80cc',
                     attributeScore:90},
                     {....} ,{...}
                    ]
              }, 
            ,{...}
         ]}
         ,{...}
      ]
```

I tried a filter like this

```
const fil = trucks.filter(function(item) {
    return item.wheels.some(function(tag) {
      return tag.mechanics.some(function(ques){
        return ques.attributeScore <= 25;
      });
    });
  });
```

but it returns an empty array . My expected return array type should be

```
trucks:[
     {wheels:[
             {name:"xyz",
              mechanics: [
                     {engine:'50cc',
                     attributeScore:100},
                     {....} ,{...}
                    ]
              },
            ,{...}
         ]}
      ]
```

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: You must be clearer. What exactly will you filter? Can you post an example of what you'd get after filtering this example?

Comment: @OscarPaz . Sorry updated the question now

Answer (score 2):

Try this now,

```
var fill = trucks.map(function(item) {
    return item.wheels.map(function(tag) {
      return tag.mechanics.filter(function(ques){
        return ques.attributeScore == 100;
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: I need all the contents of the array after the filter is applied , but this chops the parent objects and returns only the child

Comment: Yes. Parents are object. So we can't slice the object in filter. Its only for array

Comment: Meaning this only returns the child array !! Not the nesting

Comment: According to your structure it will return only child

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking, I think this function should do the trick:

```
_.map(trucks, truck => ({ 
  ...truck,
  wheels: _.filter(_.map(truck.wheels, wheel => ({
    ...wheel,
    mechanics: _.filter(wheel.mechanics, m => m.attributeScore > 90)
  })), wheel => wheel.mechanics.length),
}));
```

It's not a terribly elegant solution, but I wind up with the same answer as you were hoping for in your original post.